# MySQL Query for Average Grade of last 2 attempts

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

```
quiz userid  attempt grade

1      3        1     33

1      3        2     67

1      3        3     90

1      3        4     20
```

Now, I want the last two attempts i.e., 4 and 3 and I want average grade of these 2 grades i.e, 90 and 20
Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Use `ORDER` and `LIMIT` to get the 2 last attempts and the [AVG aggregation function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg) :

```
 SELECT AVG(grade) AS average FROM (
   SELECT grade FROM table 
   WHERE userid = 3
   ORDER BY attempt DESC LIMIT 2) AS t
```

Comment: Hi nick rulez,                                                       Your query gives an error "#1054 - Unknown column 'average' in 'field list'. What could be the error

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list both test results separately, with the average in each row, then something like this maybe (otherwise you just need the subquery for the average of the two tests):

```
SELECT userid, attempt, grade, 

( SELECT AVG(grade)
    FROM table
      ORDER BY attempt DESC LIMIT 0, 2 ) AS avg_grade

FROM table
ORDER BY attempt DESC LIMIT 0, 2;
```

Comment: The query is totally query, not even showing grade, something like number it was displaying '1324038246'